# How to configure and launch AWS automator template for particular region?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Beginner]

Hi,

I discovered AWS has the automator feature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ops-automator/overview.html).

My requirement is to take daily snapshots and copy the snap from us-east-2 to us-east-1.

I am not understanding how do I configure the template for `Amazon EC2 Create Snapshot Template` and `Amazon EC2 Copy Snapshot Template` found here(https://github.com/awslabs/aws-ops-automator/blob/master/deployment/ops-automator-latest.template) and setup a scheduler to run daily on these tasks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used boto3 and AWS Lambda to setup code to copy snapshot region to region.